# Is there any function for zoom in zoom out background with sticky background only elements need to zoom

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to create zoom in zoom out functionality with sticky background
only elements need to zoom that present in background without changing
position

Comment: Can you please provide some code? We need some context to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You've not provided a lot of context for me to work with. But, if you wanted to increase the size of an element without it moving, I think the `transform: scale()` css function would work perfectly.